# How does yum know to look at the newest release when given a specific version in the .repo file?

Tags: mongodb, yum

I was looking at the [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/) on installing Mongo on an EC2 instance. I added the following to `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo`

```
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

Everything worked as expected. However, I was able to run `sudo yum install mongodb-org`. I never said `sudo yum install mongodb-org-4.0` like the repo file, so how is it setup such that if I run `install mongodb-org` that it's linked to the `mongodb-org-4.0.repo` file? I tried for example running `sudo yum install mongodb-or` and it didn't do anything. There must be some linking but I don't know where it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[mongodb-org-4.0]` is just the name of the repo, the package names that is available in this repo is not connected to the name of the repo.

If you go to https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/ and into its RPMS subfolder, you will see the actual RPM packages you can install from this repository, e.g.

```
mongodb-org-4.0.0-1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm
```

Such a package name is divided into many parts. The important ones here is the package name:

```
mongodb-org
```

It's version number

```
4.0.0
```

You can have yum install that package by it's package name `yum install mongodb-org` , or to get a particular version, you could do a `yum install mongodb-4.0.0` .
There's other components of the rpm filenames as well, such as the first `-1` which is the RPM release number, the tag `amaz1` and the architecture `x86_64`

When using yum install, you need to provide at least a full package name or a full package name + full version when installing it. Just a partial `yum install mongodb` is not going to work.

Note also that it is up to the packager what is part of a package name, one can make a package that also includes a version number, such as mongodb-4.0 , with a version number of 4.0.0. So the full filename could have been `mongodb-org-4.0-4.0.0-1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm` , in this case, you would need to install it with yum install mongodb-org-4.0 or mongodb-org-4.0-4.0.0